# ASP.NET Trace - Custom HttpModule

Tags: asp.net, debugging, trace, system.diagnostics

We have developed our custom HttpModule.
 Now I want to add ability to trace it, and see the trace results in standart ASP.NET tracing page (or trace.axd). I try to use `System.Diagnostics.Trace.Write("FILTER TEST");` to write trace information. This works everywhere except of HttpModule. I added a trace listener in web.config, but it only shows traces that were written during the page lifecycle. How i can see the trace information that i write in HttpModule and how I can add this information to ASP.NET trace page?

```
<trace>
  <listeners>
    <add name="WebPageTraceListener"
         type="System.Web.WebPageTraceListener, System.Web, Version=2.0.3600.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
  </listeners>
</trace>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use System.Web.IisTraceListener? See: http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/how-to-add-tracing-to-iis-managed-modules

Answer (score 0):

I usually use TraceSource and it works fine even within custom HttpModule.

All you need is :

- Declare a source (you can use as many sources as you want in your code, it depends of what you want for the granularity over your tracing) - (more information on TraceSource [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.aspx)):

  ```
  public class MyModule : IHttpModule
  {
      public static readonly TraceSource MyTraceSource = new TraceSource("MySource", SourceLevels.Off);
  (...)
  }
  ```
- Within your code, use TraceEvent whenever you need your source to dump something in the trace (more information on the traceEvent method [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.tracesource.traceevent.aspx)) :

  ```
  MyModule.MyTraceSource.TraceEvent(TraceEventType.Information, 0, "Message that'll be dumped in the trace");
  ```
- In your config file you can enable/disable only the tracesource you want at the level you want (information, warning, error, ...)

  ```
  <system.diagnostics>

      <trace autoflush="true"/>

      <sharedListeners>
          <add name="myListener" initializeData="..." type="..."/>
      </sharedListeners>

      <sources>
          <source name="MySource" switchName="VerboseSwitch" >
              <listeners>
                  <clear/>
                  <add name="myListener"/>
              </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="OtherSource" switchName="OffSwitch" >
              <listeners>
                  <clear/>
                  <add name="myListener"/>
              </listeners>
          </source>
      </sources>

      <switches>
          <clear/>
          <add name="OffSwitch" value="Off"/>
          <add name="VerboseSwitch" value="Verbose"/>
          <add name="InformationSwitch" value="Information"/>
          <add name="WarningSwitch" value="Warning"/>
          <add name="ErrorSwitch" value="Error"/>
      </switches>

  </system.diagnostics>
  ```

Here you can find a really great article on the trace subject : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/149251/Debugging-Tracing-and-Instrumentation-in-NET-and-A

Hope this helps !